# WebDriver - sendKeys to browser not work in Firefox?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to send keys to browser(not element) using this code:

```
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.sendKeys("Hello! World!");
            action.perform();
```

It works well in Chrome and IE8, but get the result `World` in Firefox!

I am using Firefox 22 and Selenium WebDriver 2.32.0

Is it a bug? Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you typing in some hotkey to access some functionality? Where do you expect the text to appear? I tried it with Selenium 2.33.0 and Firefox 21 on Windows XP. I opened a browser and immediatelly ran your code - `"Hello! World!"` showed in my URL bar as expected. What did you do differently?

Comment: I want to simulate typing some code to a code editor (CodeMirror) in the browser . It seems there is something wrong when send the key `!` to CodeMirror editor in firefox.

Comment: I tried send keys to a normal textarea, and works fine. Maybe its a bug of CodeMirror.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox 22 will not be supported until Selenium 2.34.0 (It may work for some scenarios at the moment, but generally speaking it doesn't work).

I would suggest rolling back to FF20 if you want Selenium 2.32.0 to work, or FF21 if you want to upgrade to Selenium 2.33.0.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have FF20, but tried FF10, and it works fine.